# Multivariate Copulas in Python

Tags: python

I would like to compute a Copula of a k-dimensional vector in Python, where k > 2.

When k=2, I found the [AMBHAS package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ambhas/0.4.0), which seems to work fine, but as far as I can tell it only applies to 2-dimensional, i.e., bivariate, copulas.

After digging a bit more, I found [scikits.statsmodels](http://pydoc.net/scikits.statsmodels/0.3.1/scikits.statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.copula/) but it is in sandbox form as far as I can tell.

I could code this up manually myself, that's not an issue, but I was hoping to save myself the trouble of doing so by using a standard package.

Is there a multivariate Copula package in Python available that I simply couldn't find?

Comment: There is not much available in Python. github search also doesn't find much. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4046 (Also what is available is not BSD/MIT compatible which rules out any inclusion in statsmodels.)

Comment: Aside scikits.statsmodels has been renamed a long time ago to statsmodels  http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic on StackOverflow but there is a dedicated stackexchage for software recommendations.

Comment: FYI, there is now a proper submodule in statsmodels. Still not released but will be under: `statsmodels.distributions.copula`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `copulae` package. The docs can be found [here](https://copulae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

https://pypi.org/project/copulae/

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/copulae

Comment: Looks like a great start to a comprehensive solution, looking forward to future updates.

Comment: how does `pycopula` compare to `copulae` in terms of  quality for multi-dimensional copulas? The `copulae` documentation examples don't show any plotting capability whatsoever.  https://github.com/blent-ai/pycopula

Comment: @develarist, `copulae` is sort of a port from the R's `copulas` package but does not contain plots yet. Realized it might actually be in bad taste to discuss this on SO so you could raise an issue in the [github repo](https://github.com/DanielBok/copulae).

Answer (score 4):

There is a python package for multivariate Gaussian copula
https://pypi.org/project/copula/

The corresponding Github repository : [github](https://github.com/ashiq24/Copula)

install through pip:

`pip install copula`

usage:

```
from copula import pyCopula
data = [[2,1,2,4],[3,1,7,4],[2,9,1,0],[3,6,1,6] ]
cop = pyCopula.Copula(data)
samples = cop.gendata(3)
print(samples)
[2.697128268374179, 6.29726013955287, 2.983951810593502, 2.1149729235834496], [3.0, 1.0, 6.831369733333171, 4.631091408593663], [2.147377031275032, 6.75098812552581, 1.9789800708813163, 1.1200891337867478]]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23781731)

Comment: ok, I have improved my answer. I think I just followed the pattern of answers in this post @Gsk

Comment: you're right, all the answers are 'link only', even the accepted one. Only your answer was reported in the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review) queue, that's why I've seen only yours! Upvoting since is the only answer properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

For vine-copula you may try one or all of the following:

[pyvine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvine/0.4.2)

[starvine](https://github.com/wgurecky/StarVine)

[pyvinecopulalib](https://github.com/vinecopulib/pyvinecopulib)

All of these python packages seem to a bit less capable or as well tested as the R package: [VineCopula](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VineCopula/index.html).  All of these packages can fit and sample from vine copula when k > 2.